# Vue-cil3 multi-entry page after npm run build problems

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3, serve

Two different single-page application entries are set through the page property of vue.config.js, which is normal when running in `npm run serve` mode, but it runs the service with `serve -s dist` after `npm run build`, regardless of the entry of the route. Always use index.html

vue.config.js
-->

```js
pages:{

    index: {
        entry: './src/main.js',
        template: './public/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html',
        chunks: ['chunk-vendors','chunk-common','index']
    },
    mindex: {
        entry: './src/views/Mobile/main.js',
        template: './public/mindex.html',
        filename: 'mindex.html',
        chunks: ['chunk-vendors','chunk-common','mindex']
    }
}
```

Comment: What URL are you opening in your browser?

Comment: Also, what is the `-s` flag? I don't see it mentioned in the documentation ~ https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-serve

Comment: serve version is 9.4.0。use --help can find -s is --single(rewrite all not-found requests to 'index/html') ~ https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#general-guidelines

Comment: Ah, you're using https://github.com/zeit/serve. Thanks for clarifying